# XSLT Template not producing element names correctly

Tags: xml, xslt, sequence, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have an XSLT stylesheet with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="row/*">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <saxon:assign name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$count+1" /></saxon:assign>
        <xsl:variable name="node-value" as="xs:string" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="node-name" as="xs:string"><xsl:value-of select="preceding::fielddescription/name(*[$count])" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="current-node" as="xs:string"><xsl:value-of select="preceding::fielddescription/.[$count]" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test=".[not(self::F2 or self::F7)]">
            <xsl:element name="{$current-node}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=".[self::F2]">
            <UPCs>
                <xsl:element name="{$current-node}"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></xsl:element>
            </UPCs>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=".[self::F7]">
            <xsl:element name="{$current-node}">
                <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(normalize-space(replace(., '[/ ]', '-')))" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

What I want it to do is process each element given within a nodeset like this:

```
<fielddescription>
   <F1>ExternalId</F1>
   <F2>UPC</F2>
   <F3>Name</F3>
   <F4>Description</F4>
   <F5>ProductPageUrl</F5>
   <F6>ImageUrl</F6>
   <F7>CategoryExternalId</F7>
</fielddescription>
```

and produce new elements with tag names matching the values of each element in the `<fielddescription>` for every `<row>` the stylesheet finds. So far, all of my stylesheet works except for this template; it keeps producing nodes with tags that are the entire sequence name:

```
<Product removed="false">
  <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>ED003-QCX</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  <UPCs>
    <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>031878025147</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  </UPCs>
  <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>Sealy Naturals-Cotton Crib Mattress Pad</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>Give baby plush comfort from natural cotton fibers with the innovative Sealy Naturals-Cotton Crib Mattress Pad.</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>http://www.kolcraft.com/sealy-naturals-cotton-crib-mattress-pad.html</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>http://www.kolcraft.com/media/catalog/product/e/d/ed003-qcx-1_1_4.jpg</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  <ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>bedding-pads</ExternalIdUPCNameDescriptionProductPageUrlImageUrlCategoryExternalId>
  <Attributes>
    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
      <Value>ED003</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute id="BV_FE_EXPAND">
      <Value>BV_FE_FAMILY:ED003</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
</Product>
```

What is my template doing wrong? I should also note that I used the `<saxon:assign>` feature because I didn't know how else to get the stylesheet to work with a variable that would update... I know there is probably a better way to do this with recursion, but I couldn't figure out a way to get it to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: The `current-node` variable is defined as a child of the `for-each` group at the start of the template: `<xsl:variable name="current-node" as="xs:string"><xsl:value-of select="preceding::fielddescription/.[$count]" /></xsl:variable>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
<xsl:template match="row/F2">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer"><xsl:number count="*"/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="node-name" as="xs:string" select="name(preceding::fielddescription/*[$pos])"/>
            <UPCs>
                <xsl:element name="{$node-name}"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></xsl:element>
            </UPCs>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/F7">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer"><xsl:number count="*"/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="node-name" as="xs:string" select="name(preceding::fielddescription/*[$pos])"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$node-name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(normalize-space(replace(., '[/ ]', '-')))" />
            </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/*[not(self::F2 or self::F7)]">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer"><xsl:number count="*"/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="node-name" as="xs:string" select="name(preceding::fielddescription/*[$pos])"/>

            <xsl:element name="{$node-name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:element>


</xsl:template>
```

Depending on where and how you use apply-templates in ancestor element templates you might be able to replace the `<xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer"><xsl:number count="*"/></xsl:variable>` with `<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>`. But we would need to see the rest of the code to tell.

Comment: Your fix worked. :) Thank you!

I had also found another fix to my problem, I was using the `name()` of the `<fielddescription>` nodes, and not the `text()` of those nodes.